# Delay splash screen and render app(iframe)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, iframe, phonegap-build

This is an issue on both my android and IOS app, i dont really know how to explain this but basically I have delay the splash srceen for 12 mill seconds, after this I get [image] then a whitescreen for about 2 seconds then the app renders. Correctly, I have tried delaying the splash screen for 20 mill seconds to see if the app was just taking too slow but its not the case. This is the code

**config.xml**

```
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />  
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="12000" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1.0" />
```

** index.html**

```
   <html>
<head>
<title>Example App</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>


<script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Global InAppBrowser reference
var iabRef = null;


function onDeviceReady() {
iabRef = window.open('https://www.example.com/app', '_self', 'location=no,toolbar=no');

iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { 
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
});

document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
}, false );
}
</script>
<body>
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/app" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas why this is happening? and how to solve this? I have google around and try different solves but still the same issue. I have a feeling its the **iframe** but how can i still do this using the iframe?

Comment: Are you aware that both [Google and Apple frown on apps](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005a) that are website wrappers?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 **"Provide a webview of a website not owned or administered by you (unless you have permission from the website owner/administrator to do so)"** if you read carefully you will see it says `not owned` i do not owned "example.com" but i do own the website in question

Comment: Okay @James. My purpose in this is to save developers the heartache of working weeks and months on developing an App - only to have it tossed out. Would you like a tutorial (with source) on this exact subject (your issue)?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 yes please if thats is possible

Answer (score 1):

@James,
Okay. I'm going to point you to three tutorials that show work for you. One caveat, this tutorials are only intended for [*Phonegap Build*](https://build.phonegap.com/), a cloud-based build service by Adobe/Phonegap. The tutorials are mobile-device friendly.

The first tutorial you may not need. It simple reinforces the *Phonegap Build* concept. The point is with *Phonegap Build* you are not using *CLI* or an *IDE*.

- [An HTML Boilerplate for Phonegap](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/2015/BLOG.2015-06-10.jssnippets.html)

Next is the demo app to do your splashscreen. It is included as a larger demo/example batch of "core" plugins available for Cordova/Phonegap.

- [Ten (10) Phonegap Demo Apps with Source Code](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/2015/BLOG.2015-05-12.codesnippets.html)

The last tutorial is the one you are looking for. This is an example of *how to open an external webpage within phonegap using the *whitelist* system*. <s>I have not had time to write a full tutorial for this, but I think you can "get it".</s> I forgot I did do the tutorial

- [Tutorial: Phonegap Build external webpage in iframe with whitelist example](https://jssnippets.wordpress.com/2016/02/16/phonegap-build-external-webpage-in-iframe-with-whitelist-example/)
- [tutorial-html5ui-hide-show](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/tutorial-html5ui-hide-show)

One last note on the whitelist. It is required as of [Cordova Tools 5.0.0](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/04/21/tools-release.html) (April 21, 2015). For *Phonegap Build*, that means since [`cli-5.1.1`](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/06/16/phonegap-updated-on-build/) (16 Jun 2015)

Lastly, you started your post by saying,

> *basically I have delay the splash srceen for 12 mill seconds*. (sic)

12 parts out of 1000 parts of a second cannot be detected. So, I'm not sure what you mean by this.

If you need further explanation on this, I can append to this post. -Best of Luck.

Almost for forgot the [DEMO](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/examples/html5/tutorial-html5-hide-show/)

Comment: thanks. I have tried hiding the then showing the iframe on **DeviceReady** and still no luck but it seems to have removed those lines shown in the image in my question above although the whitescreen still shows after the splash screen, it wouldnt really affect UI unless the user is just a **pain**

Comment: @James your issues in not completely clear to me what remaining issues you are trying to resolve. Can you please move to [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap). There is also more help there as well.

Comment: the original issue was that the splash screen wasn't long enough but after trying the solutions you provided above, it still wasn't enough because no matter how long the splashscreen was, after it has disappear i still see the whitescreen for about 5 screens before the InAppBroswer has finish loading the webapp. I have edited the question with a new index.html which i have tried. Basically the logic I am trying to go for which hasn't work, is to only hide the splashscreen when Inapp broswer has finish using the function **loadstop**.

Comment: @JesseMonroy640 I believe this might be the right logic to only hide the splashscreen when inAppBroswer has finish loading the webapp. With my limited knowledge and understanding I have tried the above code shown in my question but have failed. Do you have any other logic or correction you might want to share please. Thanks

Comment: Move conversation to [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap)